# Consulta SQL (aprendiendo) (group by)

Tags: mysql, sql

que tal estoy aprendiendo bases de datos, estaba resolviendo unos ejercicos pero me atore con estas tres consultas me podrian ayudarme y decirme como serian y el por que?
Muchas gracias y saludos a todos.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

1. Consulta que obtenga el Nombre de cliente, Id de pedido, Fecha, Nombre productos, Cantidad, Precio y Tipo de Articulo ordenado por Id de cliente

Mi query:

```
Select 
Clientes.Nombre, Productos.Nombre, Fecha, 
Cantidad, Precio, Tipo, Pedido.idPedido
from 
Clientes, Pedido, DetallePedido, Productos
where Clientes.idCliente=Pedido.idCliente 
and Pedido.idPedido=DetallePedido.idPedido 
and DetallePedido.IdProducto=Productos.idProducto
```

2. Consulta que obtenga el Total de pedidos agrupado por Id de Cliente hasta la fecha indicada

`Select Total From Pedido Group by date and idCliente` (no se si este bien, esa es mi idea)

3. Consulta que obtenga la Cantidad de Productos agrupado por Tipo y Id de Cliente
   `Select Cantidad From Detalle Pedido` (eso es lo que pienso que es despues no se que hacer) dice agrupar segun yo entiendo es con Group By

Comment: No puse lo que yo llevaba porque estoy seguro que esta mal, no por solo preguntar pero gracias.

Comment: Listo, ya añadi mis querys, los dos que llevo :)

Comment: ¿Cuál es la pregunta?

Comment: Y bien. ¿Probaste la primera consulta? Funcionó? Probaste la segunda? QUé viste que te hizo falta en la tercera. La recomendación-no-respuesta es que montes las cuatro tablas con algunos registros de prueba y pruebes tus consultas. Sin miedo, amigo.

Answer (score 0):

Para la primera consulta, faltaria agregar `ORDER BY Pedido.idCliente`.

La segunda consulta debe ser una suma de los totales, y la fecha es una condicion (hasta cierta fecha, es decir menor o igual):

```
Select idCliente, SUM(Total) From Pedido Group idCliente WHERE fecha<='YYYY-mm-dd'
```

Para la tercera, necesitas nuevamente hacer SUM() usando las tres tablas Pedido, DetallePedido, Productos unidas por sus claves y agrupar segun lo indicado

```
SELECT Productos.Tipo, Pedido.idCliente, sum(DetallePedido.cantidad) as cantidad 
FROM Pedido, DetallePedido, Productos 
WHERE ....  /* condiciones de union semejantes a la primera consulta*/
GROUP BY Productos.Tipo, Pedido.idCliente
```

Answer (score 0):

Te comparto una posible solución

Consulta 1:
La tienes bien, te sugiero usar los tab para darle un poco de orden a la consulta y no te enredes cuando te toque chequear toda la consulta, de resto estaba bien lo único que hice fue agregarle unos 'ALIAS' que nos ayuda a agilizar un poco la consulta y no sea necesario que le pongas todo el nombre de la tabla si no el alias, y agregarle el ordenamiento por la casilla solicitada ten en cuenta que el ordenamiento se puede dar por dos formas ascendente o descendente por defecto es ascendente pero si quieres que sea al contrario lo único que haces es agregarle desc ejemplo: ORDER BY A.IdCliente desc

```
Select  A.Nombre,
    D.Nombre, 
    D.Fecha, 
    C.Cantidad, 
    C.Precio, 
    D.Tipo, 
    D.idPedido 
FROM Clientes A,Pedido B, DetallePedido C, Productos D
where A.idCliente=B.idCliente 
and B.idPedido=C.idPedido 
and C.IdProducto=D.idProducto
ORDER BY A.IdCliente
```

Consulta 2:

Te brindo dos posibles soluciones ya que es un poco abierto la pregunta, la consulta A esta esperando esperando la fecha indicada ya que puede que quieras saber solo la cantidad total vendida por cliente en una fecha especifica

La consulta B: Realiza un conteo agrupándolo por id cliente y la fecha así puede visualizar las ventas de totales de los clientes todas las fechas cargadas en la tabla

Consulta A

```
Select count(Total),
       Id de Cliente
From Pedido 
where FECHA = 'FECHA_INDICADA'
Group by Id de Cliente
```

Consulta B

```
Select count(Total),
        Id de Cliente,
        FECHA
From Pedido 
where FECHA = 'FECHA_INDICADA'
Group by Id Id de Cliente,FECHA
```

Consulta 3 Es muy parecida a la anterior solo que con un campo diferente, ten en cuenta que se usa group by cuando se tienen una funcion como AVG(),COUNT(),SUM(),MAX(),MIN() y no recuerdo si existen mas

```
Select count(A.Cantidad),
       B.Tipo,
       C.Id de Cliente
From Detalle Pedido A, productos B, pedido c
WHERE A.ID_PRODUCTO = B.ID_PRODUCTO
AND B.ID_PEDIDO = C.ID_PEDIDO
group by Tipo, Id de Cliente
```

Espero te haya ayudado